# How to get parent props from child composition component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My goal is reduce every letter prop from child (**Palata**) component, how can i achieve this ?

**index.js**

```
<Block letter="I" mb={16}>
  <Palata letter="I" start={4} end={9}/>
  <Wall/>
  <Empty/>
  <Palata letter="I" start={10} end={15}/>
  <Empty/>
  <Palata letter="I" start={16} end={17}/>
  <Empty/>
  <Palata letter="I" start={18} end={21}/>
  <Wall/>
  <Palata letter="I" start={22} end={27}/>
  <Empty/>
  <Palata letter="I" start={28} end={33}/>
</Block>
```

**Block.js**

```
export default function Block({ letter, mb, children }) {

    return (
        <div className={"flex mb-" + mb} >
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

there is a question, how to pass **Block** component letter prop as data to **Palata** component or

**Palata.js**

```
export default function Palata ({ letter, start, end }) {
  // med postlar
  const mps = ['I4', 'G1', 'E1', 'C1', 'A1', 'I13', 'G10', 'E10', 'C10', 'A10', 'I27', 'G25', 'E25', 'C25', 'A21',]
  const palataNumbers = []

  for (let index = start; index <= end; index++)
    palataNumbers.push(index)

  return (
    <>
      {palataNumbers.map((item, index) => {
        const isMP = mps.includes(letter + item)

        return (
          <button key={index} className={isMP ? 'med-post' : 'palata'}>
            {isMP ? 'MP' : letter + item}
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

or how to get parent letter prop from inside **Palata** component?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can use React Context API or Redux state management to do that.

Comment: thanks @RobinMollah for advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access props of parent component.

Also don't mutate data in body of function, it will run on every render.

```
  for (let index = start; index <= end; index++)
    palataNumbers.push(index)
```

Can use [context](http://%20https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples)

```
export const LetterContext = React.createContext('');

export default function Block({ letter, mb, children }) {
  return (
    <LetterContext.Provider value={letter}>
      <div className={'flex mb-' + mb}>{children}</div>
    </LetterContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function Palata({ start, end }) {
  // med postlar
  const mps = [
    'I4',
    'G1',
    'E1',
    'C1',
    'A1',
    'I13',
    'G10',
    'E10',
    'C10',
    'A10',
    'I27',
    'G25',
    'E25',
    'C25',
    'A21',
  ];
  const palataNumbers = Array(end - start)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_el, index) => index);

  // context
  const letter = React.useContext(LetterContext);

  return (
    <>
      {palataNumbers.map((item, index) => {
        const isMP = mps.includes(letter + item);

        return (
          <button key={index} className={isMP ? 'med-post' : 'palata'}>
            {isMP ? 'MP' : letter + item}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

But this way Palata should always be used only inside Block component.
Should be a better way to solve your task.

Comment: ooo thanks for the help bro! it solve my problem, thanks for other advices